# KDE 5.15: Missing taskbar

Tags: kde, taskbar

I am having an issue with kde 5.9, task bar is not showing anymore. Desktop wallpaper is black. I can still open application with CTrl+F2. I tried few commands and get this:

[image]

Any idea on how to show task bar again ?

Thank in advanced

```
    test@test:~/.config$ kstart5 plasmashell 
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended
test@test:~/.config$ org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/code/LayoutManager.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/LayoutManager.js")
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/code/FolderTools.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderTools.js")
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:300:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
trying to show an empty dialog
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/code/LayoutManager.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/LayoutManager.js")
trying to show an empty dialog
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/code/uiproperties.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/uiproperties.js")
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
Plasma Shell startup completed
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Application Launcher" with a weight of 13
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Digital Clock" with a weight of 37
libkcups: 5
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 7409
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 17 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...
Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Re-raising signal for core dump handling.
```

distro:
    cat /proc/version

@ElvisVinicius @Linux version 4.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019.

```
test@test:~/.config$ inxi -Fxxz
System:    Host: noums Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.7 (Qt 5.9.5) dm: sddm,sddm Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 80MK v: Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: VIUU4 v: SDK0J40709 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: C6CN34WW date: 10/29/2015
           Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK serial: N/A
Battery    BAT1: charge: 40.9 Wh 79.1% condition: 51.7/66.0 Wh (78%) volts: 8.5/7.5
           model: Simplo BASE-BAT serial: <filter>status: Charging
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-6500U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Skylake rev.3 cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10368
           clock speeds: min/max: 400/3100 MHz 1: 500 MHz 2: 500 MHz 3: 500 MHz 4: 500 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1916
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 3200x1800@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.2 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d70
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-46-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24f3
           IF: wlan0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 512.1GB (88.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_MZNLN512 size: 512.1GB serial: <filter> temp: 43C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 454G used: 407G (95%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.08GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0C mobo: 29.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 277 Uptime: 1:59 Memory: 3874.7/15947.5MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0 alt: 5/6
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191 running in konsole) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: **1**: Please install *inxi* and then post the output of `inxi -Fxxz`. **2**: Do you see a normal log in screen? **3**: Can you create a new user and login as that user? Does that user also have the same problem?

Comment: @DKBose I updated

Answer (score 9):

At first, try restarting the Plasmashell.

In **KRunner**, run:

> kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell

Could you please have more details? Distro? Video card? Open-source driver or proprietary driver?

Comment: hi @ElvisVinicius  The first command show this error "Application plasmashell could not be found using service org.kde.plasmashell and path /MainApplication."; The last command show this: Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
....

Comment: command above spat the same error as @dmx, however just `plasmashell` revived the taskbar

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't tweaked your taskbar much, you can add a new panel by simply right-clicking on your Desktop, and then `Add Panel > Default Panel`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been an active KDE member for one year...

but after many discussions with admins for not fixing KDE crashes and denying it. I have to quit that narssicistic community.

For now I tested it with Debian 11.4 in the last KDE:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`t` in that black screen wallpaper, that will open Konsole. Type:

```bash
~$ rm .config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

Now you can test it:

```
killall plasmashell

plasmashell
```

But I recommend you to restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `plasma-desktop` in command line. This worked for me.